# Error 11004 on Local NetWork with Winsock Client

Tags: c++, network-programming, winsock

### Problem

I am using the code to connect to localhost on Hercules HW terminal as Server and it works.

Then i tried to set the Server on another computer on the local network on other computer.

The message error is given for WSAGetLastError() `11004`

What is wrong? I just can't figure out.

### Code

The code for a client with Winsock is:

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <time.h>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "2112"
#define DEFAULT_PROTO SOCK_STREAM

int main()
{
    char Buffer[128];
    // default to localhost
    char *server_name = "localhost";
    unsigned short port = atoi(DEFAULT_PORT);
    int retval, loopflag = 0;
    int i, loopcount, maxloop = -1;
    unsigned int addr;
    int socket_type = DEFAULT_PROTO;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct hostent *hp;
    int first = 1;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET  conn_socket;

    //    srand(time(NULL));
    if ((retval = WSAStartup(0x202, &wsaData)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Client: WSAStartup() failed: Error %d\n", retval);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    else
        printf("Client: WSAStartup() is OK.\n");

    printf("Defina o nome ou IP do servidor[default = localhost]:\n");
    //    scanf( "%s" , Buffer );
    gets_s(Buffer);
    if (Buffer[0] != 0)
        server_name = Buffer;

    //    server_name = &Buffer;

    if (isalpha(server_name[0]))
    {   // server address is a name
        hp = gethostbyname(server_name);
    }
    else
    { // Convert nnn.nnn address to a usable one
        addr = inet_addr(server_name);
        hp = gethostbyaddr((char *)&addr, 4, AF_INET);
    }

    if (hp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Client: Endereco IP nao identificado \"%s\": Error %d\n", server_name, WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Client: gethostbyaddr() esta OK.\n");
    memset(Buffer, 0, 128);
    printf("Defina a porta do server[default = 2112]:\n");
    gets_s(Buffer);
    if (Buffer[0] != 0)
        port = atoi(Buffer);

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    memcpy(&(server.sin_addr), hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
    server.sin_family = hp->h_addrtype;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);

    conn_socket = socket(AF_INET, socket_type, 0); /* Open a socket */
    if (conn_socket <0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Client: Erro ao abrir o socket: Error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    else
        printf("Client: socket() esta OK.\n");

    printf("Client: Cliente conectando com: %s.\n", hp->h_name);

    conn_socket = socket(AF_INET, socket_type, 0); /* Open a socket */
    if (connect(conn_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Client: connect() falhou: Error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    else
        printf("Client: connect() esta OK.\n");

    loopcount = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Using Visual Basic 2015 to compile, with: `Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions`

```
_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

### Tests

- Using `telnet` and `ping` works on the other server created using Hercules HW terminal.
- Using the Hercules HW terminal as Client on computer A and as Server on computer B also works, so i think it is somthing with my code.
- Using `nmap -p 2112 192.168.1.134`

The result is:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.134

Host is up (0.00s latency).



PORT     STATE SERVICE

2112/tcp open  kip

MAC Address: 00:19:BB:F7:48:29 (Hewlett Packard)



Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.31 seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

> **WSANO_DATA 11004**
>
> Valid name, no data record of requested type.
> The requested name is valid and was found in the database, but it does not have the correct associated data being resolved for. The usual example for this is a host name-to-address translation attempt (using gethostbyname or WSAAsyncGetHostByName) which uses the DNS (Domain Name Server). An MX record is returned but no A record—indicating the host itself exists, but is not directly reachable.

Your code is failing at `gethostbyaddr(...)`. This is because the DNS on your router has no DNS record for your computer.

Having address, port, and protocol, you should directly attempt to connect to the server with it.

Also, gethostbyaddr has been deprecated: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738521(v=vs.85).aspx

For reference on how to set up your socket to connect see http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#connect

in beej's code you'll see a getaddrinfo call. That supports hostnames as shown, or dotted ip strings, so you should be able to nuke the following code from your sample:

```
if (isalpha(server_name[0]))
{   // server address is a name
    hp = gethostbyname(server_name);
}
else
{ // Convert nnn.nnn address to a usable one
    addr = inet_addr(server_name);
    hp = gethostbyaddr((char *)&addr, 4, AF_INET);
}
```

Comment: I edited with the result, although already made a test with telnet on that port